# Overlap bars in highchart's columnrange plot

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Below is one example of `columnrange` chart using `highcharts` library -

http://jsfiddle.net/bogaso/4h68vtfj/

Is it possible to overlap every pair of bars and corresponding point (as plotted as scatter-plot) on top of each other using chosen `z-index` and `color`?

I also intent to have rounded corner with radius `9999px` for every bar.

Any pointer will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable grouping and set `borderRadius`:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    grouping: false
  },
  columnrange: {
    borderRadius: 9999,
    ...
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fus3qyjz/

**API Refertence:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.columnrange.borderRadius

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.columnrange.grouping